# NSFileManager copy NSURL to apps document dir

Tags: ios, objective-c

This should be so simple yet I am struggling with it so bad. All I want to do is copy a NSURL file from its location to my apps document dir. I don't want to rename the file and would like to keep the same name. Note this file is coming from an email attachment.

This is code I have so far

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL])
    {
        NSLog(@"url: %@ ...", url);

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;

        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES);
        NSString* documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        //Not sure what to do here. I could parse URL and get the last string out of it
// which is the file name but I am not sure that's easiest way to do things.
        //[fileManager copyItemAtURL:url toURL:backupDir error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Email Copy Error: %@ ...", error);

    }
    return YES;
}

file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/1401045C-8738-458A-954A-EC30729626E1/Documents/Inbox/almonte-2.ttf ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you were already on the right path(!). Create the destination path
from the destination directory and the last path component of the url:

```
NSString *destPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
```

and copy the file from source to destination:

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:[url path] toPath:destPath error:&error];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the call to `copyItemAtPath:` will fail if a file with the given name already exists. This should be checked and handled appropriately.

Comment: @SamBudda: You are welcome. But consider also rmaddy's comment. Since you have no control over the source file name, it might be appropriate to generate unique file names such as "file 1.txt", "file 2.txt" if necessary.

Comment: Sure, I plan to delete the file and then have it copied over.